# Best practice to check duplicate string data before insert data using Entity Framework Core in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need an advice for my code. What I want to do is insert a row into a table using Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core.

Before inserting new data, I want to check if email and phone number is already used or not.

I want to return specifically, example if return = x, email used. If return = y, phone used.

Here's my code

```
public int Insert(Employee employee)
{
    var checkEmail = context.Employees.Single(e => e.Email == employee.Email);

    if (checkEmail != null)
    {
        var checkPhone = context.Employees.Single(e => e.Phone == employee.Phone);

        if (checkPhone != null)
        {
            context.Employees.Add(employee);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return 1;
        }

        return 2;
    }

    return 3;
}
```

I'm not sure with my code, is there any advice for the best practice in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I just don't like these "magic numbers" that indicate the result of your checks.... how are you or how is anyone else going to know what `1` or `2` means, 6 months down the road from now??

I would suggest to **either** at least create a constants class that make it's more obvious what these numbers mean:

```
public class CheckConstants
{
    public const int Successful = 1;
    public const int PhoneExists = 2;
    public const int EmailExists = 3;
}
```

and then use these constants in your code:

```
public int Insert(Employee employee)
{
    var checkEmail = context.Employees.Single(e => e.Email == employee.Email);

    if (checkEmail != null)
    {
        var checkPhone = context.Employees.Single(e => e.Phone == employee.Phone);

        if (checkPhone != null)
        {
            context.Employees.Add(employee);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return CheckConstants.Successful;
        }

        return CheckConstants.PhoneExists;
    }

    return CheckConstants.EmailExists;
}
```

and also in any code that calls this method and need to know about the return status code.

**Alternatively**, you could also change this to an **enum** (instead of an `int`):

```
public enum CheckConstants
{
    Successful, PhoneExists, EmailExists
}
```

and then just return this enum - instead of an `int` - from your method:

```
public CheckConstants Insert(Employee employee)
{
    var checkEmail = context.Employees.Single(e => e.Email == employee.Email);

    if (checkEmail != null)
    {
        var checkPhone = context.Employees.Single(e => e.Phone == employee.Phone);

        if (checkPhone != null)
        {
            context.Employees.Add(employee);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return CheckConstants.Successful;
        }

        return CheckConstants.PhoneExists;
    }

    return CheckConstants.EmailExists;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback.
I think the is the same with my code, but the different is we need to define a constant to handle the return type.

Answer (score 0):

1. merge two database check to one Query
2. use SingleOrDefault instance of Single

   ```
   public int Insert(Employee employee)
   {
       var checkEmail = context.Employees.Select (e=>new {e.Email , e.Phone }).SingleOrDefault(e => e.Email == employee.Email || e.Phone == employee.Phone);

       if (checkEmail == null)
       {
           context.Employees.Add(employee);
           context.SaveChanges();
           return 1;
       }
       else if (checkEmail.Email == employee.Email)
           return 3;
       else
           return 2;
   }
   ```